# Chrome DevTools. Не отображаются подсказки в javascript коде. Как исправить?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Пишу javascipt код в Google Chrome (Версия 65.0.3325.181). Находится всё в локальном файле.

Когда пишу код в консоли, тогда подсказки/автодополнение появляются в полной мере, и автоматически и после нажатия Ctrl+Пробел.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если я пишу тот же самый код в .js файле, то появляющиеся подсказки вообще никак не относятся к объекту.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему так происходит?

**И как это исправить?** Т.е. как сделать так, чтобы при написании javascript кода в .js файле появлялись нормальные подсказки, как если бы я писал этот же код в консоли.

Вот код, если кому-то надо:

```
var time = 3;
var speedFirstCyclist = 12;
var speedSecondCyclist = 14;

// вычисление дистанции
var calculateDistance = function (time, speedFirstCyclist, speedSecondCyclist) {
    //debugger;
    var distanceOfFirstCyclist = speedFirstCyclist * time;
    var distanceOfSecondCyclist = speedSecondCyclist * time;
    var totalDistance = distanceOfFirstCyclist + distanceOfSecondCyclist;
    return totalDistance;
}

// условия
var buySomeBread = function (eggs) {
    if (eggs) {
        return 10;
    }
    else {
        return 1;
    }
}

// цикл while
var washNextItem = function (itemNext) {
    while (--itemNext) {
        console.log('В раковине ' + itemNext + ' предметов');
    }
}

washNextItem(10);

var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

console.log(Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length));
console.log(arr);

// Объекты

var wizard = {
    name: 'Вася',
    age: 23,
    color: 'синий',
    male: true,
    bag: ['фаербол',23,'палка'],

    say: function () {
        console.log('aaaaaaaaa');
    }
};

resultBread = buySomeBread(true);
console.log('bread', resultBread);
var result = calculateDistance(8,9,44);
console.log(result);

/*
////////////////////////////////////////////
canvas
////////////////////////////////////////////
*/

// DOM-элемент канваса
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

// Контекст отрисовки
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
//ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';


var gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(150,72,0,150,72,72);
gradient.addColorStop(0, 'green');
gradient.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(0,255,0,0)');
ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
ctx.fillRect(0,0,300,150);

ctx.strokeRect(75,0,150,150);
//ctx.clearRect(0,0,300,500);



// Рисовать контурами

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(100,100);
ctx.lineTo(80,60);
ctx.lineTo(110,80);
ctx.lineTo(125,40);
ctx.lineTo(140,80);
ctx.lineTo(170,60);
ctx.lineTo(150,100);
ctx.lineTo(150,100);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(140,90,110,90,100,100);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
ctx.fill();
```